# Change the features of Prophet plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, facebook-prophet

While using `model.plot(forecast)` the figure that appears has small labels and x/y values.

**Is there any way to customize customize prophet's figures ?**

Answer (score 9):

I found there is a way to customize the options in `fbprophet` such as increasing size of labels or tick values.

```
fig = model.plot(forecast, xlabel='Date', ylabel='Value')
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_title("Title", size=34)
ax.set_xlabel("X", size=34)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", size=34)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=24)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=24)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`Prophet.plot`](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/v0.5/python/fbprophet/forecaster.py#L1502) is quite limiting.

However, the [`fbprophet.plot.plot`](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/v0.5/python/fbprophet/plot.py#L42) function allows the option of specifying the figure size. The default is `(10, 6)` *e.g.*

```py
from fbprophet.plot import plot

plot(model, forecast, figsize=(20, 12))
```